# Which include syntax is recommended?

Tags: gitlab, include, to-be-continuous

We have a copy of to-be-continuous at Orange, which is currently used like this:

```
include:
  # Python template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/python"
    ref: "1.2.2"
    file: "/templates/gitlab-ci-python.yml"
```

However I have no idea how the sync works with the Orange repo, and I'm thinking it's better to make all projects directly include the gitlab.com link for faster access to new functionnalities, what do you think, do you expect any issues, security or operational wise?

```
include:
  # Python template
  - remote: 'https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/python/-/raw/1.2.2/templates/gitlab-ci-python.yml'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To-be-continuous at Orange are syncronised every night with gitlab.com. So you don't miss any newer functionalities. My suggestion is to use 1st include, because our internal repo have more customisation for our needs like devops-store variant, ODE..

Answer (score 1):

Prefer use first include for all current cases.

You have to use second include for example to validate a new functionality not yet merged.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The [include/remote](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) *may* work but requires that your GitLab server has a direct access to the referenced link (`gitlab.com` in your case).

/!\ the `include/remote` syntax doesn't not support double include: when you're trying to include a template that itself includes a (local) template.